# How to send value between React.js Frontend and Express.js Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I would like to send 'cookieValue' to my backend but I'm not quite sure how to and haven't been able to find any good resources online.

Currently, I don't believe that my 'cookieValue' actually has a value when I try to send it to my backend. I am also getting a waring saying that 'cookieValue' is declared but never used in my 'findCookie function'. Below I have my current code, any help would be appreciated.

Front End Code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router";
import { useState } from 'react'

let backEndResponse = null


function SendCookie() {
    
    const [cookieValue, setCookieValue] = useState("");

    if (document.cookie != null) {
           const cookieValue = document.cookie
                .split('; ')
                .find(row => row.startsWith('Auth='))
                .split('=')[1];
    
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', {
            cookieValue,

        }).then(getBackEndResponse => {
            return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/auth', { withCredentials: true }).then((res) => {
                res.render(backEndResponse);
            })
        });

    } else {

    }
}



const useAuth = () => {
    if (backEndResponse) {
        const authorized = {loggedIn: true}
        return authorized && authorized.loggedIn;
    } else {
        const authorized = {loggedIn: false}
        return authorized && authorized.loggedIn;
    }
};

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
    const isAuth = useAuth();
    return isAuth ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}

export default ProtectedRoutes
```

Backend Code:

```
app.post('/auth', (req, res) => {
    const authCookie = req.body.cookieValue

    if (authCookie === result) {
        backEndResponse = true
    } else {
        backEndResponse = false
    }
});

app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
    res.render(backEndResponse)
});
```

Comment: Your function `findCookie` defines a `cookieValue` only as a _local_ variable, which is lost again when the function finishes. But you never call this function anyway, so why did you define it?

Comment: That was a mistake on my part I will edit the question. I am still getting the same errors, however. I believe my error is happening because of the values I put into the useState function.

Comment: If the cookie is [`httpOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#httponly), you cannot access it in Javascript, so it will not appear in `document.cookie`.

Comment: More fundamentally, cookies _come_ from your backend (or else your frontend will not be able to read them anyway), and the browser will automatically send them back with any subsequent request to the same backend. Your backend can access them as [`res.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.cookies). You need not write any extra code for that.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly you are telling me that I should get rid of the code on my frontend that retrieves the cookie and just write code on my backend that retrieves the cookie and checks if it is correct instead?

Comment: Yes, you should do so.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies come from your backend, and the browser will automatically send them back with any subsequent request to the same backend. Your backend can access them as [`res.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.cookies). You need not write any extra code for that.